# Reading a file in VB.NET one character at a time

Tags: .net, vb.net, text, file-io

How do I read a text file character by character in VB.NET?

i have a program in FORTRAN 77 which reads one character at a time
put them in an array of 80 or 132 characters (i guess the old screen and printer widths) and searches for words.

e.g. "height" "weight" "size" ":" "=" "185" "1.85" "cm" "m" etc etc

Maybe there are other ways to do that in VB.Net but i want to understand the methodology of the specific program

Comment: Can you give more background? Why would you want to do this? Why not read in the whole string at once?

Answer (score 5):

```
Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader( "yourfile.txt" )
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        Dim buffer(1) As Char
        reader.Read(buffer, 0, 1)
        'do something with buffer(0)'
    End While
End Using
```

As Jayden suggested, you would normally read a file line-by-line.  I'm taking for granted that you have some reason for wanting to do so one character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty slow to read a byte at a time, but Harpo's answer will do that. If you want an alternative, `b = System.IO.ReadAllBytes(filename)` will be a lot faster, and then you can process the data one byte at a time in the byte array b. Alternatively, you can use `s = System.IO.ReadAllText(filename)` and process the characters in the string s.